# random command strange behavior

Tags: bash, shell, random

RANDOM prints different output:

```
[root@manage /root]# echo $RANDOM
7207
[root@manage /root]# echo $RANDOM
8761
[root@manage /root]# echo $RANDOM
29922
```

RANDOM prints Same output:

```
[root@manage /root]# value=`echo $RANDOM`
[root@manage /root]# echo $value 
5286
[root@manage /root]# value=`echo $RANDOM`
[root@manage /root]# echo $value
5286
[root@manage /root]# value=`echo $RANDOM`
[root@manage /root]# echo $value
5286
```

I can't get this strange behavior. Can anyone help me to solve it?

Comment: Simple solution is `value=$RANDOM`, but that doesn't answer why `$(echo $RANDOM)` prints the same thing on every invocation (memoizing?).

Comment: i wasn't able to reproduce the issue. can you check your variables again?

Comment: I can reproduce it in zsh, but not in bash. Related: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2005-01/msg00239.html. Perhaps zsh didn't get the memo? Test case: `echo $(echo $RANDOM)`. Seems the seed isn't getting regenerated in subshells.

Comment: @user95711 which shell are you using? `echo $SHELL`

Comment: GNU bash, version 1.14.7(1)

Comment: Can't reproduce on `GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release`

Comment: well thats how it works till bash 3.0. if you need a change try to get a bash newer than 3.0+ @tjameson has given a url. you can see how it used to work till 3.0 there.

Comment: Well,I can't change my Bash version. As I have too old kernel..If any alternative you can tell me.

Comment: Why can't you upgrade your kernel? What OS are you running? I think even RHEL 5 has bash > 3, which is the oldest supported Linux OS I know of (except for extended support).

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are seeing it is because every time `echo $RANDOM` is run, it is run on a new 'shell' and hence it has the same starting seed value.  Try `echo $RANDOM; echo $RANDOM` and you will see different numbers. 
btw, I dont see the behavior in BASH, but I see it in ZSH.